# How can I select all non-unique field1s where field2 is never x?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the dataset below:

```
field1 field2
a      1
a      2
a      3
b      1
b      2
b      4
c      2
c      2
c      3
```

How can I determine which values for `field1` are never associated anywhere in the table with a `field2` value of 4?

The result would be

```
field1
a
c
```

`SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE field2 <> 4` will include b because it appears in the table multiple times with other `field2` values - how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

You can `group by field1` and put the condition in the having clause:

```
select field1
from tablename
group by field1
having sum(field2 = 4) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

use not exists

```
select t1.* from table t1
where not exists( select 1 from table t2 where t1.field1=t2.field1 
                 and t2.field2=4)
```

or use not in

```
select * from table t1
where t1.field1 not in ( select field1 from table where field2=4)
```